# How to scroll page by using TouchActions appium method?

Tags: java, scroll, appium, appium-android

I wrie automated tests for Android native application and forced with scroll problem.

I need to scroll Android application page, and googled next method for this : http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.scroll(element, 10, 100);
action.perform();
```

But in first line I’m getting an exception " java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen"

My environment is: java, jdk 1.8.0_65, appium 1.6.1

P.S. I tried use TouchAction - from these [Automating mobile gestures](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/), it works, but methods are deprecated.

```
.press(100,100) 
.moveTo(100,100)
```

P.P.S. I also tried to execute adb command, smth like this:

```
  "adb -s shell input touchscreen swipe " + startx + " " + starty + " " + endx + " " + endy + " " + duration"
```

but it also doesn't work for me and I want to use native appium methodsif it possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported **TouchAction** from **io.appium.java_client.TouchAction**

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver); 
action.press(PointOption.point(115, 650)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(115, 350)).release().perform();
```

> Updated: You need to upgrade your selenium-java version to latest stable version

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;

//AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
TouchActions action1=new TouchActions(driver);
    action1.scroll(element,x1,x2).perform();
```

Comment: TouchActions is not TouchAction. These are different libraries . Actually TouchAction - I tried and it works fine, but methods are deprecated (moveTo) see my topic. But TouchActions - has scroll method, thich I wanna use, but get an eror on initialization TouchActions object line

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfectly working commands.

```
     TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver); 
             action.press(PointOption.point(115, 915)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
                             .moveTo(PointOption.point(115, 150)).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

action.press(PointOption.point(115,915))
      .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
      .moveTo(PointOption.point(115, 150))
      .release()
      .perform();
```

It is good and it is working.